# How do I use matlab POWER fucntion properly

Tags: matlab

I have to do a small program in matlab for my class, which checks basic information
about the sides of a triangle and its angles and i came up with this

```
clc
a= input('enter the length of the side a ');
b=input('enter the length of the side b ');
c=input('enter the length of the side c ');


k="This triangle is ";

if (a+b>=c || b+c>=a || a+c>=b)

    if (a==b && b==c)
        a='equilateral ';
        
    elseif (a==b && a~=c|| a==c && a~=b || b==c && b~=a)
        a='isosceles ';
       
    else
    a=' scalene';
    end

    if ((a^2)+(b^2)==c^2 || (a^2)+(c^2)==b^2 || (b^2)+(c^2)==a^2)
        b='right.';

    elseif (a^2+b^2>c^2 || a^2+c^2>b^2 || b^2+c^2>a^2)    
        b='acute.';

    else
        b='obtuse.';
    end
d=k+a+b;
disp(d)
else disp('sorry, you cant build triangle with those')
end
```

and i got a message about line 21
Error using  ^
Incorrect dimensions for raising a matrix to a power. Check that the matrix is square and the power is a
scalar. To operate on each element of the matrix individually, use POWER (.^) for elementwise power.

I've tried replacing ^ with .^ and also adding () but nothing worked. help pls

Comment: You are assigning strings (right, acute, etc) to `a` and `b`. Try using different variable names so you don't get errors in the `if` statements.

Comment: `if (a+b>=c || b+c>=a || a+c>=b)` this condition is always true, even for triplets that cannot form a triangle such as 1, 1 and 100.

Comment: ok then, fixed thing with variables and it works right now, but I have no idea how to check if you can build that triangle using only if, do you have any idea?

Comment: ok, replaced || with && and it works perfectly, thank you for help